# How to lock all published posts so only admin can unlock delete and update permission

Tags: permissions

Lets say one has a AUTHOR role that has published thousands of posts and one wants a way to lock all the published posts by admin so that the author can not delete or update the posts..is there a way to do this?

I have not see anything like this online and this is a major issue.
Without restricting delete and update permission, an author can just delete all posts and wipe the whole blog!

Answer (score 0):

Think i found the perfect plugin for it finally
https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced